# SAS datastep/SQL select latest record from multiple records with same ID

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql, datastep

For example I have a dataset as below:

```
id Date
1  2000/01/01
1  2001/01/01
1  2002/01/01
2  2003/01/01
```

By datastep or sql, how could I get the record with id = 1 and latest Date 2002/01/01?
Help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this sql.

```
select id,max(Date)
from yourtable
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help, I forgot about max() and group by.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the entire record and the data is sorted as shown (BY id and DESCENDING date), you can use this data step:

```
data want;
   set have;
      by id; /* you don't need to specify date here */
   if last.id;
run;
```

This give you the most recent record for each id.

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

```
proc sql;
create table my id as
select id,max(Date)
from yourtable
where id=1;
quit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this as well

```
proc sql;
create table my id as
select id,Date
from yourtable
where Date=(select max(Date) where id = 1 )
quit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Sort your data by id and descending date then*/

data want;
   set have;
      by id; /* you don't need to specify date here */
   if first.id;
run;
```